# How to restore my old wallet from address and privatekey?

Tags: wallet-recovery

Few years ago I created a bitcoin wallet. I did it with some command line util which generated bitcoin address from template. At the bottom of output util tells me to store this in private place. I did it and forgot about bitcoin for few years. I attach util output below this post.

Now I would like to restore my wallet and hope to find some bitcoins on it. How can i do it with official Bitcoin Core wallet?

Comment: You should not share your private key with anyone, that can allow any user with that private key to access your bitcoin.

Comment: @asterisk yes I know. i share few letters only. Rest of key hidden by white paper as you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A step by step process has been explained in the below link

[How to import private keys in Bitcoin Core](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Help:How_to_import_private_keys_in_Bitcoin_Core_0.7%2B)

You need to sync your Bitcoin Core to see your balance.

If you want to access your BTC easily and without downloading the whole blockchain, then go to [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/wallet/)

Sign up and after logging in, go to settings. Then in settings, you will see addresses as shown below:

[image]

Then click on Import Bitcoin Address as shown:

[image]

Then add your private key as it is in the form as shown:

[image]

Click import, and you will be able to use your BTC again.

Please follow that and let me know if you were able to retrieve the coins.

Comment: should I sync Bitcoin Core first?

Comment: Yes, you should sync bitcoin core. But that can take a long time, as the blockchain size is very high (138 GB as of Oct 17). So, if you just want to access Bitcoin without Bitcoin Core, please check my answer again, I have updated it.

Comment: Ok I will wait while Bitcoin Core synced because I do not trust online services. And will try step by step from your first answer https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Help:How_to_import_private_keys_in_Bitcoin_Core_0.7%2B

Comment: No worries mate. There are also other lite clients where you have the complete control and you don't need to download entire blockchain unless you want to mine.

Comment: i did importprivkey . It works!

Comment: Do accept this as the right answer if it worked for you :) @alexey2baranov

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Bitcoin Core (bitcoin-qt) and wait till sync will complete. It is better to keep private key locally.

Then in bitcoin-qt chose `Help menu` > `Debug window` > `Console`.

Type `importprivkey privkey` where `privkey` yours private key. And press Enter.

After rescaning you would be able to see you balance in this application.